# Is it possible to redirect to a destroy method of a resource controller using jquery in laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, modal-dialog

I am using resource controller for comments.
I have a link to delete a comment in my blade.

```
<a href="" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete"></span></a>
```

if i click on it a jquery dialog pop ups. the code for dialog box is as below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $('.edit-delete  span.delete').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<div id="dialog" class="pull-center"></div>').appendTo('body').html('<div"><h4>Are you sure you want to delete this comment?</h4></div>')
        .dialog({           
            autoOpen: true,
            modal   : true,
            title   : 'Confirm',
            buttons: {
                "Yes" : function(){                     
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    $(location).attr("href", " {{what do i put here?}} ");

                },
                "No" : function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });


    });

});
```

But no surprise that redirect will not work as we need to use Delete method.How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

In your `{{what do i put here?}}` section you will want a link to the laravel route, something like this

```
{{ route('routeName', ['id' => $comment->id]) }}
```

see https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

Note this will need to use a GET method, however it might be more normal to use a form and then you can use PUT or DELETE which might make more sense in this case, alternatively I often use AJAX from this sort of request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method: https://gist.github.com/JeffreyWay/5112282
to delete a comment or whatever by using a link. Include the javascript that is provided in the link above somewhere on your header and place the html link on your view:

```
<a href="delete/{{$id}}(or whatever delete route you have)" data-method="delete" data-token="{{csrf_token()}}" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this x ?">
```

Then your route can be :

```
Route::delete('delete/{id}','your_controller@your_delete_method');
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
We need to create a hidden input field in the html as below for csrf token.

```
<input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and need to create an a tag with href as below.

```
<a class="js-ajax-delete" href="{{route('comment.destroy', $comment->id)}}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

The script would look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.js-ajax-delete').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
         var deleteUrl = $(this).attr('href');
         var token = $('#token').val();

        $('<div id="dialog" class="pull-center"></div>').appendTo('body').html('<div"><h4>Are you sure you want to delete this comment?</h4></div>')
        .dialog({

            autoOpen: true,
            modal   : true,
            title   : 'Confirm',
            buttons: {
                "Yes" : function(){

                    $(this).dialog('close');

                    $.ajaxSetup({
                           headers: {
                               'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                           }
                       });

                    //Delete request
                       $.ajax({
                           type:   'DELETE',
                           url:    deleteUrl,
                           data:   { _token :token },
                           success: function(data){
                               if (data == "true") {
                                window.location.href=window.location.href;
                               };
                           }
                       });
                },
                "No" : function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });        

    });
});
```

and the delete method in the controller would be like this:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $comment = Comment::find($id);
        $comment->delete();
        session()->flash('success', 'Comment has been deleted');
        return "true";//it has to be a string 
    }
```

to run the dialog box we need to load jQuery-UI along with jQuery ofcourse.
Hope it helps someone.